# How can I make text in my td wrap when it reaches the width of the image in my td?

Tags: html, css, html-table, word-wrap

So I have `<td>` in my table that looks like this:

```
<tr> 
    <td>
        <p class="tableText">Random text that goes on REALLY long..........</p>
        <img src="www.imageurl.com/img.png" width="33vw">
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="tableText">Random text that goes on REALLY long..........</p>
        <img src="www.imageurl.com/img.png" width="33vw">
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I want to be able to do, is the width of each `<td>` is the `width` of the image, then the text should wrap when it reaches the `width` of the image to the next line. However, instead the text is just running on.

Is there something I can do in JS/JQuery,HTML, or CSS to fix this? (preferably html/css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give the same `width` in `p`as you are giving to the `img` because they are siblings.

```css
td {
  border: red solid
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 33vw
}
p {
  width: 33vw
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="tableText">Random text that goes on REALLY long..........</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/100x100" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="tableText">Random text that goes on REALLY long..........</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/100x100" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah duh. That was obvious. Thanks, sorry for not seeing that myself!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had to wait 1 minute still.

Comment: @AshwinGupta what happened to unaccept my any answer?

Comment: Sorry, thats weird I didn't mean to do that. Must have done it when I reloaded. Re-accepted, my bad. Its working btw, tried it on my project!